# Best way to calculate overall records based on associative data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm processing the final results of competitions and its *general report* on the best trainer and which place the trainer should get.

I have already prepared associative arrays below. The `key` represents *trainer's id* and the `value` represents the *number* of medals in a category (gold, silver, bronze) *that* his/her athletes got.

```
[gold] => Array
   (
       [777777] => 4
       [333333] => 2
       [555555] => 1
       [999999] => 1
   )

[silver] => Array
   (
       [999999] => 3
       [777777] => 3
       [333333] => 2
   )

[bronze] => Array
   (
       [333333] => 6
       [777777] => 4
       [999999] => 2
   )
```

Next array associates *trainer's id* with its *name*:

```
[trainers] => Array
   (
       [333333] => Trainer 4
       [777777] => Trainer 1
       [999999] => Trainer 2
       [555555] => Trainer 3
   )
```

---

I have stuck processing the data above into final results like this. Any ideas on how it could be done elegantly? The problem is that the data is never constant and the size of the array is always different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code sample:

$gold, $silver, $bronze, $trainers are arrays with information you provided.

```
$out = [];
foreach($trainers as $trainerId=> $trainerName){
  $out[] = array(
    'id'=>$trainerId,
    'name'=>$trainerName,
    'gold'=>isset($gold[$trainerId])?$gold[$trainerId]:0,
    'silver'=>isset($silver[$trainerId])?$silver[$trainerId]:0,
    'bronze'=>isset($bronze[$trainerId])?$bronze[$trainerId]:0,
  );
}
uasort($out, function($a, $b){
  // Here: sort by your algorithm. Here is example:
  if($a['gold'] != $b['gold']){
    return $b['gold'] - $a['gold'];
  }
  if($a['silver'] != $b['silver']){
    return $b['silver'] - $a['silver'];
  }
  return $b['bronze'] - $a['bronze'];
});
$placeId = 1;
foreach($out as &$info){
    $info['place'] = $placeId++;
}
unset($info);
foreach($out as $info){
  echo "{$info['place']} place goes to - {$info['name']} ({$info['id']}) as he/she got {$info['gold']} gold medals, {$info['silver']} silver and {$info['bronze']} bronze";
}
```

Comment: +1 Oleg, thanks pal! It seems to produce correct results, however it will need more testing. At the moment I can say, that there is an issue with final results: `$placeId` is **incorrect**, because `$placeId` is not always corresponds with the index and `$placeId` should be `+ 1` not to start with the 0.

Comment: Fixed that. Not sure about your logic for sorting. For example, if you have 10 silver and one 1 gold medal - is it better than 2 gold medals ? :)

You should implement this logic yourself. For example you can use points system here.

Comment: Oleg, now the 4 place completely lost (I suppose as it has 0 value). The logic is simple for sports. If you as a trainer got your athletes take `2 gold, 0 silver and 0 bronze` medals, it will be better than having, let's say `1 gold, 10 silver and 10 bronze` medals.

Comment: Fixed that. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it with metrics:

```
$gold = array
   (
       '777777' => 4,
       '333333' => 2,
       '555555' => 1,
       '999999' => 1
   );

$silver = array
   (
       '999999' => 3,
       '777777' => 3,
       '333333' => 2
   );

$bronze = array
   (
       '333333' => 6,
       '777777' => 4,
       '999999' => 2
   );

$trainers = array
   (
       '333333' => 'Trainer 4',
       '777777' => 'Trainer 1',
       '999999' => 'Trainer 2',
       '555555' => 'Trainer 3'
   );


$metrics = [
  'gold' => 3,
  'silver'=> 2,
  'bronze' => 1];

$results = [];

foreach ($metrics as $arrName => $metric)
{
  foreach (${$arrName} as $trainerId => $medals)
  {
    $results[$trainerId] = ( isset($results[$trainerId]) ) ? $results[$trainerId]+$medals * $metric : $medals * $metric;
  }
}

// sorting scores (by value)
arsort($results);

// print scores
var_dump($results);

// print final results
$placeOut = '';

foreach ($results as $trainerId => $score) {
  $placeOut .= $trainers[$trainerId].": he/she has ";
  foreach ($metrics as $medalName => $metric) {
    $placeOut .= (${$medalName}[$trainerId] > 0 ? ${$medalName}[$trainerId] : 0)." ".$medalName.", ";
  }
  $placeOut .= "\n";
}

echo "<pre>".$placeOut."</pre>";

 ?>
```

Comment: That also works, thanks. It throws a warning as arrays not always balanced! ;) `Undefined offset: 555555`.